# VueJS - Display Input Image Kills Browser

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, vue.js, chromium

I have the following minimal VueJS component, which offers a file input and displays the image afterwards. For some reasons this kills my web-browsers (Firefox and Chromium tested). Here "kills" means they do not response anymore and the CPU goes crazy. I switched to a less VueJS using solution with `document.getElementById('id').src = reader.result` which also require only method only, but is Firefox still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
export default {
  name: 'test',

  template:
    '<div>' +
    '<img src="image" v-if="image">' +
    '<input type="file" @change="fileChange" />' +
    '</div>',

  data() {
    return {
      image: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async fileChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0]

      if (file) {
        this.image = await this.loadImage(file)
        console.log('Image is: ' + this.image)
      }
    },

    async loadImage(file) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onloadend = function() {
          resolve(reader.result)
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `reader.onloadend` is never called, and because of using async & await `fileChange` method never ends which causes browser to stop responding.

In order to see what is the problem you should also set `FileReader.onerror` , like this:

```
async loadImage (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onerrror = reject();
    // ..
  })
}
```

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)